# A synonym for "fearful"

Tags: synonyms

Today I saw a question [How to nurture my child to be fearful?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/19345/how-to-nurture-my-child-to-be-fearful)<sup>1</sup>, and the **fearful** in the title sounded too harsh to me. What could be used instead?

<sup>1</sup> Now titled *How to nurture my child to be cautious of her actions?*

Comment: I think you might mean "cautious".  Have you tried looking up synonyms for "fearful"?

Comment: "Cautious" doesn't quite cut the meaning of that particular word, but for the sake of overall meaning, I'll suggest that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fear gets a bad rap. There are some things that children must, for their own safety and survival, *be afraid of* (fire, snakes, scorpions, speeding cars, etc).

That said, one does not have to teach a child to **be** "fearful" (in the sense of having an abiding, continuous fearful attitude).

What you need to **instill** in them is (appropriate) **fear** of the things in their environment that can injure of kill them.

For some parents, this includes "strangers" (that's where the fine line comes between teaching some basic common-sense safety habits and instilling a morbid, crippling fear of everybody.)